# SQL Server join and update an unstructured data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

The information comes from `.pdf` unstructured files with the street address like this:

```
8/43 Herbert Street ARTARMON NEW SOUTH WALES 2064 AUSTRALIA
```

which is inserted into the table `RAW_INVOICES`:

| SITE_NAME | SITE_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 8/43 Herbert Street ARTARMON NEW SOUTH WALES 2064 AUSTRALIA |  |
| 1A 134 Old Pittwater Road, Brookvale, NSW 2100 |  |
| 90A Euston Road ALEXANDRIA NSW 2015 |  |

And I have the table `SITES`:

| SITE_ID | SITE_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| LOC-1 | Artarmon HO |
| LOC-2 | Alexandria |
| LOC-3 | Brookvale |

With this, I need a query that finds the first word in a string

```
8/43 Herbert Street ARTARMON NEW SOUTH WALES 2064 AUSTRALIA
```

that matches with the first word in the `SITES` table, `SITES_NAME` column, to get the `SITE_ID` (`LOC-1`).

So, it would find "Artarmon" on both sides, then it must get the "LOC-1" `SITE_ID`.

Same operation with the second .pdf unstructured file:

```
1A 134 Old Pittwater Road, Brookvale, NSW 2100
```

Finding `Brookvale` from `SITE_NAME` column, to get the `SITE_ID` (`LOC-3`).

...Same operation with the third .pdf unstructured file:

```
90A Euston Road ALEXANDRIA NSW 2015
```

to get the `SITE_ID = LOC-2`. And so on.. (the tables have more rows than I can display here).

Due to I do not see a join here, I was thinking about a LIKE or a case when, but I do not know the more efficient way to handle this.

Desired output:

`RAW_INVOICES` table:

| SITE_NAME | SITE_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 8/43 Herbert Street ARTARMON NEW SOUTH WALES 2064 AUSTRALIA | LOC-1 |
| 1A 134 Old Pittwater Road, Brookvale, NSW 2100 | LOC-3 |
| 90A Euston Road ALEXANDRIA NSW 2015 | LOC-2 |

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just a note, it's possible to use LIKE in a JOIN condition.

Comment: What happens if you have an address `90A ALEXANDRIA Road ARTARMON` what result do you want?

Comment: Hello @Charlieface it would find the first word that matches, which is ALEXANDRIA, and get the LOC-2.

Comment: First word in the string, or first row in `SITES` to match anywhere in the string? For the former you would probably need something like `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) * FROM SITES s ORDER BY IIF(CHARINDEX(s.SITE_NAME, i.SITE_NAME) > 0, CHARINDEX(s.SITE_NAME, i.SITE_NAME), 999999) ) s`

Comment: Hello @Charlieface Thank you so much, it would be first word in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Apply to select the first row that has a match.

To get the first word, you can use a combination of `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`. Make sure to null out `0` from `CHARINDEX`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM RAW_INVOICES i
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM SITES s
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
        ISNULL(
          SUBSTRING(
            s.SITE_NAME,
            1,
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', s.SITE_NAME), 0) - 1
          ),
          s.SITE_NAME
        )
    ) ) v(firstWord)
    WHERE CHARINDEX(v.firstWord, i.SITE_NAME) > 0
    ORDER BY CHARINDEX(v.firstWord, i.SITE_NAME)
) s;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Umlo9f5X)

Comment: that doesn't work https://dbfiddle.uk/aILmtcnZ

Comment: @nbk You got the tables backwards https://dbfiddle.uk/naUM19Ia

Comment: ok, but he wants all **three** sites and your query only gets 2

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem, that i see, that of you have the same sites name in multiple countroes, or states, you wouldn't get the correct answer, so you would need more that the site mane, to identify the row

```
UPDate RAW_INVOICES  SET  RAW_INVOICES .[SITE_ID] = SITES.[SITE_ID] 
FROM  SITES
  
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *  
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(SITES.[SITE_NAME], ' ')  
    WHERE    LOWER(RAW_INVOICES.[SITE_NAME] ) 
  LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER (LOWER(value)),'%'))
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT *  
    FROM RAW_INVOICES
```

| SITE_NAME | SITE_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 8/43 Herbert Street ARTARMON NEW SOUTH WALES 2064 AUSTRALIA | LOC-1 |
| 1A 134 Old Pittwater Road, Brookvale, NSW 2100 | LOC-3 |
| 90A Euston Road ALEXANDRIA NSW 2015 | LOC-2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PD_0RMH_)

Comment: Why use `LOWER` instead of a case-insensitive collation? And why use `LOWER` twice? Also note that results will be non-deterministic if there is more than one match.

Comment: i don't know his table or character set so this would work on case sensitive and case insensitive

Comment: So why not use `COLLATE someCaseInsensitiveCollationHere`? you can specify collations explicitly if you want.